# Family of curves that transitions smoth from linear to logarithmic

Tags: geometry, curves

I am looking for a family of curves that smoothly transitions from

$f(x)=x$

to

$f(x)=log(x+1)$

Comment: Please provide additional context or details.  The domains don't match, so do you only want this on the positive reals?  Does $tx+(1-t)\log(x)$ do what you want?

Comment: I am only looking for the positiv reals. I chose those two funtions in order do demonstrate the idea. Basically I am looking for a parameter to controll how strongly logarithmic the function is. I kown this terminology is probably verry wrong but I don't knwo how to discribe it differently.

Comment: If you take $f(x)=\begin{cases}x&(x<0)\\log(1+x)&(x \ge 0)\end{cases}$ you have a smooth curve in the sense that $f'(0)=1$ on both sides, but $f''(0+)=-1$ whereas $f''(0-)=0$, therefore $f''(0)$ cannot be defined.

Comment: One natural choice is $f_a(x) := x^{1 - a} \log^a (x + 1)$, $a \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $tx+(1-t)log(x+1), t∈[0,1]$ does the trick. to get the exact desired behaviour I had to bias $t$ a little more toward the linear part but I knew that would be the case from the beginning. For anyone curious it is used for a slider that depending on the previously chosen range either works linear for smaler ranges or logarithmic for larger ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can combine any two functions $f_0(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ using a third (interpolating) function $w(y)$:
$$f(x, y) = \biggl(1 - w(y)\biggr) f_0(x) + w(y) f_1(x) \tag{1a}\label{1a}$$
such that
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x, 0) &= f_0(x) \\
f(x, 1) &= f_1(x) \\
\end{aligned}$$
and $f(x, y)$ for $0 \lt y \lt 1$ are "combinations" of the two functions.  The interpolating function $w(y)$ defines how the two functions get mixed.

Any function that fulfills $w(0) = 0$, $w(1) = 1$, $0 \lt w(y) \lt 1$ for $0 \lt y \lt 1$ will work, but some common (symmetric) ones are
$$\begin{aligned}
w_1(y) &= y \\
w_3(y) &= 3 y^2 - 2 y^3 \\
w_5(y) &= 10 y^3 - 15 y^4 + 6 y^5 \\
w_\lambda(y) &= \begin{cases}
0, & y \le 0 \\
2^{\lambda - 1} y^\lambda, & 0 \lt y \le \frac{1}{2} \\
1 - 2^{\lambda - 1} (1 - y)^\lambda, & \frac{1}{2} \lt y \lt 1 \\
1, & y \ge 1 \\
\end{cases} \end{aligned} \tag{1c}\label{1c}$$
If you want replacing $y$ with $1-y$ to behave as if one swapped $f_0$ and $f_1$, then you do want a symmetric function, one that for $0 \le y \le 1$ fulfills $w(y) + w(1-y) = 1$.

Note that outside $0 \le y \le 1$, we actually do *extrapolation*, which may or may not make any sense at all.  Again, it depends on the behaviour of the intepolating/extrapolating function $w(y)$.

---

For example, using linear interpolation, $w(y) = y$, and $f_0(x) = x$, $f_1(x) = \log(x + 1)$, we get
$$f(x, y) = (1 - y) x + y \log(x + 1)$$
and $f(x, 0) = x$, $f(x, 1) = \log(x + 1)$, and something in between for $0 \lt y \lt 1$ using $f(x, y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have function $g_1(x)$ that applies for all $x \le x_1$, and another function $g_2(x)$ that applies for all $x \ge x_2$, with $x_1 \le x_2$, and we want to combine these into a single function $f(x)$.

As described by [Jean Marie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie) in a comment to the question, we could have $g_1(x) = x$, $g_2(x) = \log (x + 1)$, with $x_1 = x_2 = 0$.

(Whenever there exists an $x$ for which $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$, that can be used as the shared boundary.)

The important detail here is [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness).  When $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$, we have $\mathbb{C}^0$ continuity at $x$.  If their derivatives also match, we have $\mathbb{C}^1$ continuity at $x$.  Again, as Jean Marie commented, the above two functions derivatives ($d g_1 / d x = 1$, $d g_2 / d x = 1/(x+1)$) match at $x = 0$ but the second derivatives ($d^2 g_1 / d x^2 = 0$, $d^2 g_2 / d x^2 = -1 / (x+1)^2$) do not, so we have $\mathbb{C}^1$ continuity here.

The combined function is usually defined as a piecewise function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \lt 0 \\
\log(x + 1), & x \ge 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

---

When $x_1 \lt x_2$, we can "fill in" the gap using a third function, $g_3(x)$, such that it has desired smoothness at both $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Very commonly, these functions are simple polynomials, because a polynomial of degree $N$ has $N+1$ constants that can be set by fitting.

Basically, we define $g_3$ as an $N$'th degree polynomial,
$$g_3(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} C_i x^i$$
noting that its first derivative is then
$$\frac{d g_3(x)}{d x} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} i C_i x^{i-1}$$
and second derivative
$$\frac{d^2 g_3(x)}{d x^2} = \sum_{i=2}^{N} i (i-1) C_i x^{i-2}$$
and so on.  We choose $N$ so that we have the exact number ($N+1$) of unknowns $C_i$, matching the number of smoothness requirements at $x_1$ and $x_2$.  This forms a system of $N+1$ equations, which can be solved (at least numerically) using linear algebra (or any computer algebra system, like Maxima/wxMaxima, Sagemath, Matlab, Octave, Mathematica, Maple, etc.).

For example, let's say we have $g_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} x$ for $x \le 1$, and $g_2(x) = x$, for $x \ge 2$, and we want to join them with $\mathbb{C}^1$ continuity.  This means
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
g_3(1) &= g_1(1) = \frac{1}{2} \\
g_3(2) &= g_2(2) = 2 \\
\left.\frac{d g_3(x)}{d x} \right\rvert_{x=1} &= \left.\frac{d g_1(x)}{d x} \right\rvert_{x=1} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\left.\frac{d g_3(x)}{d x} \right\rvert_{x=2} &= \left.\frac{d g_2(x)}{d x} \right\rvert_{x=2} = 1 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
and we have four unknowns, so $g_3(x)$ will be of third degree (a cubic):
$$g_3(x) = C_0 + C_1 x + C_2 x^2 + C_3 x^3, \quad \frac{d g_3(x)}{d x} = C_1 + 2 C_2 x + 3 C_3 x^2$$
Fitting in the values we have a system of four equations and four unknowns,
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
g_3(1) &= C_0 + C_1 + C_2 + C_3 = \frac{1}{2} \\
g_3(2) &= C_0 + 2 C_1 + 4 C_2 + 8 C_3 = 2 \\
\left.\frac{d g_3(x)}{d x}\right\rvert_{x=1} &= C_1 + 2 C_2 + 3 C_3 = \frac{1}{2} \\
\left.\frac{d g_3(x)}{d x}\right\rvert_{x=2} &= C_1 + 4 C_2 + 12 C_3 = 1 \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
which has a single solution, $C_0 = 4$, $C_1 = -9$, $C_2 = 7$, $C_3 = -3/2$, and therefore
$$g_3(x) = -\frac{3}{2} x^3 + 7 x^2 - 9 x + 4$$
and the combined function is
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} x, & x \le 1 \\
g_3(x) = -\frac{3}{2} x^3 + 7 x^2 - 9 x + 4, & 1 \lt x \lt 2 \\
g_2(x) = x, & x \ge 2 \\
\end{cases}$$

---

Sometimes we really want $x_1 \gt x_2$, and have to "compromise" somehow for $x_2 \le x \le x_1$ instead.

This can be done using a "blending" or interpolation function $w(x)$, such that $w(x) = 0$ for $x \lt x_2$, $0 \le w(x) \le 1$ for $x_2 \le x \le x_1$, and $w(x) = 1$ for $x \ge x_1$.  Normally, we want symmetry, so that $w(x) + w(1 - x) = 1$.

If we use an intermediate variable $y$ such that it is zero at $x = x_2$ and one at $x = x_1$, i.e.
$$y = \frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2} \quad \iff \quad 1 - y = \frac{x_1 - x}{x_1 - x_2} \quad \iff \quad x = x_2 + (x_1 - x_2) y$$
then there are a couple of commonly used intepolation polynomials that can be useful:
$$\begin{aligned}
w_1(y) &= y \\
w_3(y) &= y^2 (3 - 2 y) \\
w_5(y) &= y^3 (10 - 15 y + 6 y^2 ) \\
\end{aligned}$$
noting that $w_3(y)$ is pretty close to $\frac{1 - \cos \pi y}{2}$.  Within this interval, $f(y) = (1 - w(y)) g_1(x) + w(y) g_2(x)$.

There are also interpolating functions like
$$w_\lambda(y) = \begin{cases}
2^{\lambda - 1} y^\lambda, & y \le \frac{1}{2} \\
1 - 2^{\lambda - 1} (1 - y)^\lambda, & y \gt \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{cases}$$
where $\lambda \gt 0$ determines the curvature, for when one needs a "tunable" interpolating function.

The combined function is then
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g_1(x), & x \le x_2 \\
g_1(x) w\left(\frac{x_1 - x}{x_1 - x_2}\right) + g_2(x) w\left(\frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2}\right), & x_2 \lt x \lt x_1 \\
g_2(x), & x \ge x_1 \\
\end{cases}$$
assuming a symmetric interpolating function $w$ (i.e. $w(x) + w(1-x) = 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$); and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g_1(x), & x \le x_2 \\
g_1(x) \left(1 - w\left(\frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2}\right)\right) + g_2(x) w\left(\frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2}\right), & x_2 \lt x \lt x_1 \\
g_2(x), & x \ge x_1 \\
\end{cases}$$
for a general interpolating function $w$ for which $0 \le w(x) \le 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Obviously, the degree of smoothness, and even the exact behaviour of $f(x)$ in the interpolated interval, depends completely on the interpolating function $w$.  This means that in practice, the combined function (and its derivatives, up to the degree of smoothness/continuity desired) is plotted for interpolation function candidates.

For "tunable" interpolating functions, the "tuning" variables (like $\lambda$ above) can be fitted to some desired condition; the more conditions, the more complex interpolating function is needed.

Comment: I really apprechiate the answer and I think it is excelent. But, and I know this one is on me, it answerd an other question. But that is due to my lack of capability to properly describe what I am looking for. [This wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurvenschar) side showes the concept. So I think what I am lokking for is f functin that when plugged in $a=0$ results in the linear curve and for $a=1$ resulting in a logarithmic curve and for $a=0.5% something in bitween that is not totaly linear but also not totaly logarithmic. f that makes any sense.

Comment: given that your anser is a really good match for anyone looking for two curve "stitched" together smoothly I'm not shure if I should accept this anser and as a new question for the sake of having this one out in the wild. If so what would be a better terminology for my new question so I avoid the same confusion.

Comment: @EN20:  Oh! So, you're looking for $$f(x, y) = \bigl(1 - w(y)\bigr) f_0(x) + w(y) f_1(x)$$such that $f(x, 0) = f_0(x)$ and $f(x, 1) = f_1(x)$, with other values of $y$ interpolating between the two functions, and the interpolating function $w(y)$ describing how the two are mixed for $0 \lt y \lt 1$.  Perhaps I need to edit or add to my answer?

Comment: you nald it. Sounds exactly like what I'am looking for. I'd say adding might be the best in this situation, since than anyone comming here for the other question can still find your solution.

Comment: @EN20: I wrote a new answer, and decided to leave this one alone.  Feel free to downvote this one, because it did not answer your question!

Comment: thank you very mutch I actually upvoded both because I think depending on how one interprets my question both anser it verry well